# php dom skipping some part in an Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have checked some similar solutions but none of them exactly fix this problem.

When this xpath is called and echoed:

```
$xpathResult = $xpath->query("//a[@href = '../page.php?passto={$_GET['passto']}']/..");
```

from this html:

```
<td class="cell">
  <a class="link"  href="../page.php?passto=iframecontent.pdf>
HYPERLINK
  </a> Bla bla bla...
</td>
```

This will turn up:

```
HYPERLINK Bla bla bla...
```

Now, what should I do to skip and hide the 'HYPERLINK' along in the xpath so that only the 'Bla bla bla...' turns up?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) will solve this.

```
$xpathResult = $xpath->query("//a[@href = '../page.php?passto={$_GET['passto']}']/..");
echo $xpathResult = trim(strstr($xpathResult, ' '));//"prints" Bla bla bla...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your XPath to only match text nodes *directly* contained in the parent node:

```
//a[@href = '../page.php?passto={$_GET['passto']}']/../text()
```